# Can I use pandas to extract rows after a condition?

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe

Can I use pandas to extract specific values after a condition?
For example with a table such as this

```
U         A         B         C
0  1.438161 -0.210454         0
1 -0.283780 -0.371773         0
2  0.552564 -0.610548         0
3  1.931332  0.649179         1
4  1.656010 -1.373263         1
5  0.142682 -0.657849         1
6  1.754264 -0.610548         0
7  1.341232  0.649179         0
8  1.656010 -1.373263         0
9  0.944862 -0.657849         0
```

Can I grab two rows after C changes from 1 to 0 so that I get this row?

```
6  1.754264 -0.610548         0
7  1.341232  0.649179         0
```

I know that the following code will grab every row with C=0, but I just want the two rows.

```
from numpy.random import randn 
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(6,3),columns=list('ABC')) 
df.loc[df['C']=0]
```

Thank you

Comment: Does it occur just one time this change? Or more than once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with [`Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) and [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) :

```
c = df['C'].astype(bool)
#c = df['C'].eq(1)
df.loc[df['C'].where(c).ffill(limit=2).mask(c).notna()]

   U         A         B  C
6  6  1.754264 -0.610548  0
7  7  1.341232  0.649179  0
```

or [`groupby.nth`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html)

```
c = df['C'].cumsum()
df.loc[c.gt(0)].groupby(c,as_index=False).nth([1,2])
```

**EDIT**

> This works for more than one group of 1 together

```
print(df)
    index  U         A         B  C
0       0  0  1.438161 -0.210454  0
1       1  1 -0.283780 -0.371773  0
2       2  2  0.552564 -0.610548  0
3       3  3  1.931332  0.649179  1
4       4  4  1.656010 -1.373263  1
5       5  5  0.142682 -0.657849  1
6       6  6  1.754264 -0.610548  0
7       7  7  1.341232  0.649179  0
8       8  8  1.656010 -1.373263  0
9       9  9  0.944862 -0.657849  0
10      0  0  1.438161 -0.210454  0
11      1  1 -0.283780 -0.371773  0
12      2  2  0.552564 -0.610548  0
13      3  3  1.931332  0.649179  1
14      4  4  1.656010 -1.373263  1
15      5  5  0.142682 -0.657849  1
16      6  6  1.754264 -0.610548  0
17      7  7  1.341232  0.649179  0
18      8  8  1.656010 -1.373263  0
19      9  9  0.944862 -0.657849  0
```

---

```
c = df['C'].astype(bool)
#c = df['C'].eq(1)
df.loc[df['C'].where(c).ffill(limit=2).mask(c).notna()]




    index  U         A         B  C
6       6  6  1.754264 -0.610548  0
7       7  7  1.341232  0.649179  0
16      6  6  1.754264 -0.610548  0
17      7  7  1.341232  0.649179  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `diff` to find where values in C change then use the index of where this occurs to index your original dataframe:

```
ix = np.where(df['C'].diff() == -1)[0][0]
df.iloc[[ix, ix+1], :]
```

This works for the first instance that C changes from 1 to 0.

Comment: `This works for the first instance that C changes from 1 to 0.` so this doesn't work

Comment: I don't understand why upvote it, 
this just doesn't work if there are two groups of 1 together

Comment: From the documentation for [`numpy.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html): _When only condition is provided, this function is a shorthand for np.asarray(condition).nonzero(). Using nonzero directly should be preferred, as it behaves correctly for subclasses._